# Globbing in git log to show certain branches

Tags: git, glob, git-log

I have a project with lots of branches, and I want to log only these branches:

```
foo/bar
foo/bar-baz
origin/foo/bar
origin/foo/bar-baz
```

What glob pattern do I need to do this? I've tried `foo/bar*`

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph foo/bar*
```

which shows me `foo/bar` and `foo/bar-baz` only.

Comment: Try `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --branches=foo/bar* --remotes=origin/foo/bar*`

Comment: @ElpieKay I would like to do it in a single pattern if possible

Comment: then try `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --glob=*for/bar*`

Comment: @ElpieKay this does appear to work, although for some reason `--glob=foo/bar*` doesn't show foo/bar-baz. Also it seems it was coincidental that using a glob pattern without `--glob=` actually worked at all in the question

Comment: `--glob` searches `refs/*`. `refs/` is prepended if missing. So `--glob=foo/bar*` matches `refs/foo/bar*`. But the branch `foo/bar` is actually `refs/heads/foo/bar`. Without `--glob=` it can't work but raises an error, saying something like `foo/bar*` is an unknown revision.

Comment: Oh I see! `refs/` is a folder in `.git/`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay) for the solution. This does the trick:

```
git log --decorate --oneline --graph --glob=*foo/bar*
```

You can get a better understanding of how to glob by taking a look at the `refs/` folder in `.git/`. `heads/` contains the references to the local branches the glob looks at; likewise `remotes/` contains the refs to the origin branches